# Bernoulli GLM in JAGS

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

I am getting errors of mismatched parameters for one of the predictor variables in my JAGS code and this is not producing convergence for 2 of my variables.

I am analyzing a data set of 1000 patients (observations) who had epilepsy and those who did not (1/0). Other variables are categorical - gender (male, female, LGBTQ), drug type use (diclofenac (1), bicarbonate (2) and thiazide (3)). Then, there is a continuous variable (BMI, ranging from 10:40). Below is my code. What could be wrong with it:

```
"model{
  for (i in 1:n)
  {
    epilepsy[i]~dbern(prob[i])
    logit(prob[i])<- intercept+gendereffect[gender[i]] + druguseeffect[Druguse[i]]+ BMIeffect*BMI[i]+
    interaction*gender[i]*Druguse[i]}
    intercept~dnorm(0,precision)
    gendereffect[1]<-0
    gendereffect[2]~dnorm(0,10^6)
    gendereffect[3]~dnorm(0,10^6)
    druguseeffect[1]<-0 
    druguseeffect[2] ~ dnorm(0,10^6)
    druguseeffect[3]~dnorm(0,10^6)
    intercept~dbeta(1,1)
    BMIeffect~dnorm(0,10^6)
    interaction~dnorm(0,10^6)
    precision~dgamma(10,10)
    #data# druguse, gender, BMI,n,epilepsy
    #inits# intercept,BMIeffect,gendereffect,druguseeffect,interaction,precision
#monitor# gendereffect,BMIeffect,druguseeffect,interaction,precision
}"
```

Note: I have a list created. And on R, I converted druguse and gender to integers, both ranging 1:3. But the model is not running.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  What packages are you using?  Where is you data?  Also, note that JAGS uses *precision*, not variance when defining Normal RVs.  Precision = 1/Variance.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for responding. I have never been frustrated like I have with this code.  I am using R package and running the model on runjags. My data is data frame of 1000 observations, comprising disease, coded in 0s and 1s. Drug Use coded as 1,2,3 as integers, gender coded as 1,2,3 as integers and BMI, a continous variable, ranging between 10 and 40.

Comment: I also took out the precision parameter for the intercept and replaced it with 10^6. Even without the precision parameter, the JAGS code is refusing to run, returning error that:  Error in setParameters(init.values[[i]], i) : RUNTIME ERROR:
Dimension mismatch in values supplied for druguseeffect and gendereffect.

Comment: The error would likely come from the data identifying `druguseeffect` and `gendereffect` values that were not given priors.  That is, my guess is that JAGS thinks there should be a `gendereffect[4]` or `druguseeffect[4]` that you haven't specified in the code.  This does sound strange given your comment above that the data are integers of value {1,2,3}.

Comment: Is it advisable to convert categorical variables to integers before coding in JAGS or it is better left as factor?

Comment: Priors were provided for each level of gendereffect and druguseeffect. Instead, the code runs when inits is not turned on in the runjags function, showing that both are not stochastic nodes and won't be considered in convergence.